# Energy loss in nuclear recoil

Tags: particle-physics

When a free nucleus undergoes recoil, with a kinetic energy of **K** , it emits a gamma ray with a reduced energy of $h\nu-K$ . But in a bound nucleus of a lattice , we do not find the reduced energy of gamma ray .We see it as $h\nu$ .

Why does such reduction in energy occur in case of free nucleus and not in bound nucleus?

Comment: See [Mössbauer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_effect)

Comment: But can I know how the momentum conservation can be written including the reduced mass of nucleus and the relative velocity between nucleus and core...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kinematics. Conservation of momentum  induces the smaller energy in the gamma from a free nucleus . A nucleus bound in a lattice conserves momentum with the whole lattice, and very little energy is needed for that, as momentum is mv and the mass of the lattice is orders of magnitude larger than the mass of a nucleus.

As said in the comments:

> In the [Mössbauer effect,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_effect) a narrow resonance for nuclear gamma emission and absorption results from the momentum of recoil being delivered to a surrounding crystal lattice rather than to the emitting or absorbing nucleus alone. When this occurs, no gamma energy is lost to the kinetic energy of recoiling nuclei at either the emitting or absorbing end of a gamma transition: emission and absorption occur at the same energy, resulting in strong, resonant absorption.